# How do you know what relationship to use?

Tags: database-design

I understand that there could be a relationship between the entity's, let's say, Customer and Order, but I don't understand to which table the 1, m or n belongs to when I create my own ERD... Are there any rules to understand what relationship I should use and in what order I should put the symbols (so is it 1:n or n:1)?.

In the following image I know each order has 1 customer since order_id is the primary key of the Order table. Is this the reason why there's a 1:n relationship and not a n:1? Or is it because the same customer can place an order multiple times, so the customer will be saved in the order table multiple times?

[image: rdb]

Another example:

Same question here. Why is there a 1:n relationship between t_course and t_course_taken? and why is it a 1:n relationship between t_student en t_course_taken?

[image: relationship]

Comment: **1 customer** can have **many orders**. think of it that way!

Comment: 1 student can take many courses, and a course can be taken by many students. In this case, the 'middle' 'child' table needs to be introduced so to stop a many to many relationship. Since its a child table the multiple will go on its side.

Comment: something like: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships--net-8561 will be of great use

Comment: @jbutler483 Thanks. Why is it that since its a child table the multiple will go on its sides? I'll check the link.

Comment: its a **derived table**- i.e. it has been 'made up' (using 2 (+) foreign keys as primary key)  - whereas the other two are 'real' tables.

Comment: @jbutler483 My textbook says that an entity is a synonym for a table, but I'm not sure about that. Would you say a derived table is an entity as well?

Comment: An entity is another name for a table, so yes - although, it gets into a grey area there

Comment: @jbutler483 1 customer can have many orders. What if we change the relationship from 1:n to n:1? Would we then say, an order has multiple customers? Would we have to change the foreign key?

Comment: An entity is NOT a synonym for a table.  An entity is a subdivision of the subject matter.  It's actually like a class of objects from the problem domain, using OO terminology.  A table is a data structure suitable for containing data pertaining to an entity (or to a relationship).  The data in the t_course and t_student tables REPRESENT entities.  They are not synonymous with entities.

Comment: the t_course taken table is not "made up".  The attributes semester, academic_year, and grade are part of the subject matter, just as much as the attributes of the other two tables.  The key fields are synthetic, as all foreign keys are synthetic.

Comment: @WalterMitty Can you explain what an entity is in easier terms? I dont know what a problem domain is. I've tried googling it many times but it always seems to be explained very vaguely or too abstract for me.

Comment: The "problem domain" is just OO speak for the subject matter, and may have fallen into disuse FAIK.  The word "entity" can be as generic as the word "noun" in grammar.  In fact, entities are persons, places, or things.   In the context we are speaking, courses and students are entities in the real world.  I tend to use the word "entity" only to refer to "subject matter entites".  But I've seen database literature where they make reference to "database entities" like tablespaces, or "schema entities" like tables.  If you're just getting started, this is just going to further muddy the waters.

Comment: @WalterMitty I will view an entity as a real life object/thing for now, and that tables can represent entity's in an ERD. The reason I was confused about them being synonyms is because I could have all attributes grouped together in a single table (UNF), but it would be too broad at that point to represent it as a single entity. E.g. as far as I know, the attributes of a hospital bed + the attributes of a patient in the same table cannot represent a single entity. Only till you have the normalized form they become individual entity's.

Comment: Not to further confuse the issue, but different ERD's can be at different levels of abstraction.  Originally (about 40 years ago) the ER model and ERDs were used to represent the data at a conceptual level, and were depicting the entities, relationships, and attributes.  Today, the majority of ERDs you will see floating around are really relational schematics, depicting database design, and representing tables, columns, and rows  (or tables, fields, and records depending on who you read). And a lot of otherwise competent people mix up those two levels of abstraction.

Comment: @WalterMitty Confusion, If anything, makes me think about the subject which ultimately leads to better comprehension. Data modelling isn't my strong suit, so I hope to change this :) If I understand you correctly, you're saying that originally, data modelling and ERD's was more about modelling the real life world, viewing things as entity's which have attributes, and as of now it's more about database design, how we would represent the data using tables etc? I tend to think about this subject in OO terms, so to me entity's are like objects property's are like attributes. Is this a good habit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already an accepted answer to this question, but I wanted to draw attention to one aspect of this question for the benefit of future visitors.  It's the difference between analyzing the subject matter and designing the database.

Entities and the relationships among entities are really features of the subject matter, not features of the database as such.  One discovers these features by analyzing the subject matter to find out how things work in the real world.  It's important to understand that these features are discovered, not invented.  In this sense, the relationship between courses and students is many-to-many simply because that is how it works in the real world (in every school I've ever looked at).

Once the real world is (somewhat) understood, one is ready to begin database design.  Database design is a process of invention, but the invention had better be guided by the results of the discovery done earlier.

The initial design of the database involves tables, keys, and foreign keys.  This is where normalization comes into play, and I second jbutler's recommendation to look into it.  Note also that the analysis revealed two entities with a many-to-many relationship between them, while the design results in three tables, with a couple of one-to-many relationships between the outer two (entity) tables and the middle (relationship) table.  This is how many-to-many relationships are modeled in the relational model.

This distinction between analysis and design is often overlooked by people just coming up to speed on database work.  It's possible to go wrong here.  An over emphasis on analysis can result in "analysis paralysis".  An under emphasis can result in "ready, fire, aim".

Comment: Thanks alot! I've been thinking alot about this problem... Your answer really made me think about this from a different perspective. Like you've said, since we're modelling a real life scenario, I'm thinking I should define a relationship based on what the entity's are, rather than trying to find out what the relationship would be based on the attributes and keys of each entity. Can you confirm if this is the correct way to figure out the relationship? So for example, because a company has many employees and each employee works at the same company its a 1:n relationship.

Comment: Or do you actually look at what the attributes are and the keys and try to find out what the relationship is based on that info?

Comment: It depends.  You can start at the top and work your way down.  You analyze the subject matter into entities, you discover the relationships, then you discover the attributes that describe them, using data values to be stored in the database.    Or you can start at the bottom, and work your way up.  You analyze the requirements in terms of values to be stored, you group these into attributes, and then you use these to discover the relationships and the entities.  I tend to do a little of both.

Comment: Once you have a good ER model, including the attributes, converting this to a relational database, in terms of tables and keys, is fairly mechanical, if you're willing to settle for middle of the road performance.

Comment: I found this answer to be more helpful since the point of my confusion was what relationship I should pick when modelling an ERD. You helped me realize theres multiple ways to design one, e.g. by using the normalization forms (so attributes first) or modelling entity's first, or a little bit of both if you know what you're doing :) I'm very grateful to both you and jbutler, as I've always had trouble understanding cardinality during high school.

Comment: I'm still wondering about one thing regarding cardinality: Why do we have to define the different types of relationships? What's the benefit in doing so? I like understanding the underlying concepts... Why can't we just say there's a relationship, and leave it at that? If I understand correctly, a relationship is just an SQL join between two entity's.

Comment: @user1534664 cardinality allows you to see which is the child table and which is the parent table (i.e. which table needs to be filled in first). You can't have a record in the child table with no connection to a parent, but CAN have a record in a parent table that doesn't appear in a child one!

Comment: @jbutler483 Thanks, that's what I needed to know. But that's only the case when there's referential integrity right?

Comment: @jbutler483 If I understand correctly, referential integrity means the foreign key in the child table can't be NULL, so it has to point to a valid record in the parent table. Is this correct?

Comment: yes - as the foreign key works to identify a specific record in the child table (neither primary keys/foreign keys can be null)

Answer (score 1):

Moving this to an answer:

Last comment answer: In short, yes.

However, in the first example that wouldn't make sense. One customer may have many orders, but a single order cannot belong to many customers.

**In your second example,**

A single student may enrol on many courses, and a single course may have many students. (Hence a many to many relationship). In order to combat this, We include a **child table**. Call it *studentsCourse* for simplicity.

A student can have many student courses, but a student course will now be specific to them.

A course may have many *studentCourses*, but again, a single studentCourse will belong to a single Course.

---

Making any more sense now?

---

**BTW**, I think you could make use of reading up on **Database Normalisation** (http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/) which will hopefully explain better how to break down tables (your textbook may even contain a chapter or two on the subject!)

Comment: I like this answer.  It was initially the accepted answer, and it's good enough.